# How to make an auto login to a flash site?

Tags: vb.net, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to login to a swf flash site using vb.net

**I use the code bellow to login to the first page:**

```
            Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

            For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection

                Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("name").ToString
                Dim username As String = TextBox1.Text
                Dim pass As String = TextBox2.Text
                If controlName = "xlog" Then
                    curElement.GetAttribute("Value")
                    curElement.SetAttribute("Value", username)
                ElseIf controlName = "xpas" Then
                    curElement.SetAttribute("Value", pass)
                ElseIf controlName = "Submit" Then
                    curElement.InvokeMember("click")

                End If
            Next
```

Comment: Make sure you're not violating any terms of use by decompiling. It's generally frowned upon. Read the site's Terms of Use, and if it says not to decompile/reverse engineer, you're going to want to scrap the code you got that way and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

As the platform manager of MyMaths I can tell you that decompiling our Flash content is against our terms of use. That said we appreciate that some of our users require a simpler method to sign their students straight into the service, and it is something that we are currently developing.

In the short term, I ask that you don't develop your own solution. You are more than welcome to contact our customer services team (details on website) and they would be happy to inform you when our solution is implemented.

Regards,

Darren

**MyMaths Platform Manager**